# Ignore case sensitivity in Ansible when condition?

Tags: ansible, ansible-role

I am trying to create an ansible role that depends on other roles only if the hostname of the machine it's being run on contains a certain string. For example:

```
  dependencies:
- { role: example-role, when: "'hostname' in ansible_hostname" }
```

As it is, the role will run when the hostname of the machine contains the phrase "hostname". However, many of the machines in our building have hostnames that are upper case, for example, it may contain "HOSTNAME". In this case, the above statement will not work. How can I make this work (aside from duplicating the line and putting "hostname" in all caps) to ignore letter cases?

Answer (score 14):

Convert the string to lowercase and only check that. Like this:

```
  dependencies:
- { role: example-role, when: "'hostname' in ansible_hostname|lower" }
```

Comment: how to make sure the input is lower case?

Comment: That's what the "| lower" is for.

Comment: Ok got it... I just had to apply a `|lower` right next to `'hostname'` like `when: "'hostname'|lower in ansible_hostname|lower"`

Comment: I get the `|lower` part, but for your code to work, both the strings must be lowered.

Comment: `hostname` isn't a variable. It's an already lowercase string :\

Comment: The "lower" on (any) literals helps guard against potential future chgs to the value/its case, (however inadvertent), replacing w/ a variable, etc. causing elusive regressions. Also the explicit equivalency on both sides serves as a more "at a glance" clarification of the intent of the comparison.